# What should tuple_map return?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdtuple

I want to implement a generic `tuple_map` function that takes a functor and an `std::tuple`, applies the functor to every element of this tuple and returns an `std::tuple` of results. The implementation is pretty straightforward, however the question arises: what type should this function return? My implementation used `std::make_tuple`. However, [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/201131/146724) `std::forward_as_tuple` was suggested.

To be more specific, the implementation (handling of empty tuples is omitted for brevity):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<class Fn, class Tuple, std::size_t... indices>
constexpr auto tuple_map_v(Fn fn, Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<indices...>)
{
    return std::make_tuple(fn(std::get<indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)))...);
    //          ^^^
}

template<class Fn, class Tuple, std::size_t... indices>
constexpr auto tuple_map_r(Fn fn, Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<indices...>)
{
    return std::forward_as_tuple(fn(std::get<indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)))...);
    //          ^^^
}

template<class Tuple, class Fn>
constexpr auto tuple_map_v(Fn fn, Tuple&& tuple)
{ 
    return tuple_map_v(fn, std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), 
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>>{});
}

template<class Tuple, class Fn>
constexpr auto tuple_map_r(Fn fn, Tuple&& tuple)
{ 
    return tuple_map_r(fn, std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), 
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>>{});
}
```

In the case 1 we use `std::make_tuple` which decays type of each argument (`_v` for value), and in the case 2 we use `std::forward_as_tuple` which preserves references (`_r` for reference). Both cases have their pros and cons.

1. Dangling references.

   ```
   auto copy = [](auto x) { return x; };
   auto const_id = [](const auto& x) -> decltype(auto) { return x; };

   auto r1 = tuple_map_v(copy, std::make_tuple(1));
   // OK, type of r1 is std::tuple<int>

   auto r2 = tuple_map_r(copy, std::make_tuple(1));
   // UB, type of r2 is std::tuple<int&&>

   std::tuple<int> r3 = tuple_map_r(copy, std::make_tuple(1));
   // Still UB

   std::tuple<int> r4 = tuple_map_r(const_id, std::make_tuple(1));
   // OK now
   ```
2. Tuple of references.

   ```
   auto id = [](auto& x) -> decltype(auto) { return x; };

   int a = 0, b = 0;
   auto r1 = tuple_map_v(id, std::forward_as_tuple(a, b));
   // Type of r1 is std::tuple<int, int>
   ++std::get<0>(r1);
   // Increments a copy, a is still zero

   auto r2 = tuple_map_r(id, std::forward_as_tuple(a, b));
   // Type of r2 is std::tuple<int&, int&>
   ++std::get<0>(r2);
   // OK, now a = 1
   ```
3. Move-only types.

   ```
   NonCopyable nc;
   auto r1 = tuple_map_v(id, std::forward_as_tuple(nc));
   // Does not compile without a copy constructor 

   auto r2 = tuple_map_r(id, std::forward_as_tuple(nc));
   // OK, type of r2 is std::tuple<NonCopyable&>
   ```
4. References with `std::make_tuple`.

   ```
   auto id_ref = [](auto& x) { return std::reference_wrapper(x); };

   NonCopyable nc;
   auto r1 = tuple_map_v(id_ref, std::forward_as_tuple(nc));
   // OK now, type of r1 is std::tuple<NonCopyable&>

   auto r2 = tuple_map_v(id_ref, std::forward_as_tuple(a, b));
   // OK, type of r2 is std::tuple<int&, int&>
   ```

(Probably, I got something wrong or missed something important.)

It seems that `make_tuple` is the way to go: it doesn't produce dangling references and still can be forced to deduce a reference type. How would you implement `tuple_map` (and what would be the pitfalls associated with it)?

Comment: Interesting question. But shouldn't it be the responsibility of the person writing the call to make sure the behavior is well defined? For instance, if we take `auto fn = [](auto const& x) { return std::cref(x); }; auto a = fn(2);` We would get a dangling reference, without any tuple involved. My conclusion would be to go with `forward_as_tuple` knowing that (little) caveat

Comment: Did You think of just making separate overloads/SFINAE versions for lvalues and rvalues? I think this would allow You to get the best of both worlds

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you highlighted in your question is that using `std::forward_as_tuple` on a functor that returns by value will leave you with an rvalue reference in the resulting tuple.

By using `make_tuple` you cannot keep lvalue-refs, however by using `forward_as_tuple`, you cannot keep plain values. You can instead rely on `std::invoke_result` to find out what are the types your result tuple must hold and use the appropriate `std::tuple` constructor.

```
template<class Fn, class Tuple, std::size_t... indices>
constexpr auto tuple_map_r(Fn fn, Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<indices...>) {
    using tuple_type = std::tuple<
        typename std::invoke_result<
            Fn, decltype(std::get<indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)))
        >::type...
    >;
    return tuple_type(fn(std::get<indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)))...);
}
```

This way you preserve the value category of the result of the `fn` call.
[Live demo on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a6c28c9329231a4)

Comment: Am I correct that with template argument deduction we don't need `tuple_type` and can simply `return std::tuple(fn(...)...)`? I even wanted to include this alternative into my question, but (erroneously) thought it was equivalent to `forward_as_tuple`.

Comment: @Evgeny Correct. With template deduction guides it would work I think (I am not too confident since I am not familiar with them yet though...).

Comment: @Evgeny after some [testing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a385ca7c5750e0db), it appears that the deduction guides for `std::tuple` decay their arguments... So explicit type is still the only way to go it seems!

Comment: I've just made a similar test and was going to write a comment that `std::tuple(...)` doesn't really work. :)

Comment: @Evgeny `tuple(x...)` is equivalent to `make_tuple(x...)`, with the exception that `reference_wrapper<T>` stays as `reference_wrapper<T>` and doesn't become `T&`.